# How to handle the endianness with UInt8 in a DataView?

Tags: javascript, wav, endianness, dataview, uint8array

It seems like there is nothing to handle endianness when working with UInt8. For example, when dealing with UInt16, you can set if you want little or big endian:

`dataview.setUint16(byteOffset, value [, littleEndian])`

vs

`dataview.setUint8(byteOffset, value)`

I guess this is because endianness is dealing with the order of the bytes and if I'm inserting one byte at a time, then I need to order them myself.

So how do I go about handling endianness myself? I'm creating a WAVE file header using this spec: http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

The first part of the header is "ChunkID" in **big endian** and this is how I do it:

```
dataView.setUint8(0, 'R'.charCodeAt());
dataView.setUint8(1, 'I'.charCodeAt());
dataView.setUint8(2, 'F'.charCodeAt());
dataView.setUint8(3, 'F'.charCodeAt());
```

The second part of the header is "ChunkSize" in **small endian** and this is how I do it:

```
dataView.setUint8(4, 172);
```

Now I suppose that since the endianness of those chunks is different then I should be doing something different in each chunk. What should I be doing different in those two instances?

Cheers!

**EDIT**

I'm asking this question, because the wav file I'm creating is invalid (according to https://indiehd.com/auxiliary/flac-validator/). I suspect this is because I'm not handling the endianness correctly. This is the full wave file:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const BITS_PER_BYTE = 8;
const BITS_PER_SAMPLE = 8;
const SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
const NB_CHANNELS = 2;
const SUB_CHUNK_2_SIZE = 128;

const chunkSize = 36 + SUB_CHUNK_2_SIZE;
const blockAlign = NB_CHANNELS * (BITS_PER_SAMPLE / BITS_PER_BYTE);
const byteRate = SAMPLE_RATE * blockAlign;

const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(chunkSize + 8)
const dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer);

// The RIFF chunk descriptor
// ChunkID
dataView.setUint8(0, 'R'.charCodeAt());
dataView.setUint8(1, 'I'.charCodeAt());
dataView.setUint8(2, 'F'.charCodeAt());
dataView.setUint8(3, 'F'.charCodeAt());
// ChunkSize
dataView.setUint8(4, chunkSize);
// Format
dataView.setUint8(8, 'W'.charCodeAt());
dataView.setUint8(9, 'A'.charCodeAt());
dataView.setUint8(10, 'V'.charCodeAt());
dataView.setUint8(11, 'E'.charCodeAt());

// The fmt sub-chunk
// Subchunk1ID
dataView.setUint8(12, 'f'.charCodeAt());
dataView.setUint8(13, 'm'.charCodeAt());
dataView.setUint8(14, 't'.charCodeAt());
// Subchunk1Size
dataView.setUint8(16, 16);
// AudioFormat
dataView.setUint8(20, 1);
// NumChannels
dataView.setUint8(22, NB_CHANNELS);
// SampleRate
dataView.setUint8(24, ((SAMPLE_RATE >> 8) & 255));
dataView.setUint8(25, SAMPLE_RATE & 255);
// ByteRate
dataView.setUint8(28, ((byteRate >> 8) & 255));
dataView.setUint8(29, byteRate & 255);
// BlockAlign
dataView.setUint8(32, blockAlign);
// BitsPerSample
dataView.setUint8(34, BITS_PER_SAMPLE);

// The data sub-chunk
// Subchunk2ID
dataView.setUint8(36, 'd'.charCodeAt());
dataView.setUint8(37, 'a'.charCodeAt());
dataView.setUint8(38, 't'.charCodeAt());
dataView.setUint8(39, 'a'.charCodeAt());
// Subchunk2Size
dataView.setUint8(40, SUB_CHUNK_2_SIZE);
// Data
for (let i = 0; i < SUB_CHUNK_2_SIZE; i++) {
    dataView.setUint8(i + 44, i);
}
```

Comment: I notice that you are forgetting to set byte 15 to 0x20 - the space character.

Comment: @Bergi Oh my god! The missing piece! How did you know I was supposed to add a space? It's working now :D.

Comment: Because the spec says so: "*Contains the letters `"fmt "` (0x666d7420 big-endian form)*" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single byte (`uint8`) doesn't have any endianness, endianness is a property of a sequence of bytes.

According to the spec you linked, the ChunkSize takes space for 4 bytes - with the least significant byte first (little endian). If your value is only one byte (not larger than 255), you would just write the byte at offset 4 as you did. If the 4 bytes were in big endian order, you'd have to write your byte at offset 7.

I would however recommend to simply use [`setUint32`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/setUint32):

```
dataView.setUint32(0, 0x52494646, false); // RIFF
dataView.setUint32(4, 172       , true);
dataView.setUint32(8, 0x57415645, false) // WAVE
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So my ChunkSize is 1 byte and since it's in small endian, it's positioned at offset 4. What I don't understand is why it would be positioned at offset 7 if the endian was big. What is considered the "least significant byte" and the "most significant byte"?

Comment: @maximedupre The ChunkSize is 4 bytes, from index 4 throughout 7.

Comment: @maximedupre Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Mapping_multi-byte_binary_values_to_memory

Comment: So if my value is three bytes and the 4 bytes (Subchunk1ID for example) are in big endian order, I need to place the values at index 13, 14  and 15 (instead of 12, 13 and 14)?

Comment: @maximedupre Rather: 15, 14, 13 (big endian) vs 12, 13, 14 (little endian). But as I said, you really should just use `setUint32` and `setUint16` instead of setting individual bytes by hand.

Comment: Yes, I will definitely switch to `setUint32` and/or `setUint16` once I get it right setting the order manually. I am stubborn like that =P. I just want to understand the concept better. So that would mean setting the first part (ChunkID) in reverse since the ordering is big endian - “R” at index 3, “I” at index 2, “F” at index 1 and “F” at index 0. However this makes my wave file even more invalid when I do that. (I didn't only modify the first part, I modified every part that necessitated big endian ordering)

Comment: @maximedupre sorry for the confusion, I started with the lowest byte in my comment (as you had only one byte in that example, `0x??` == `0x000000??`). Hey, this confusion is just what endianness is all about :-) `R` (0x52) is the most significant byte in the number 0x52494646, so it goes first in big-endian format. (Hint1: decimal numbers are spelled out in big-endian format in everyday writing, having the "ones" in the end, the "tens" before that, etc)

Comment: @maximedupre … (Hint2: given the age of the WAVE format, those bytes are not arbitrary: when you open the file in a text editor, the order of bytes is so that you can read them).

Comment: the bits of a uint_8 are arranged so that the most significant bit is either on the left or the right.   that's endianness

Comment: @ErikAronesty Yes, there's bit endianness, but only if you serialise the byte into a sequence of 8 bits (like [some physical/link layer protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit-oriented_protocol) do). If you already have a byte, with a value between 0 and 255, there's no endianness.